# unable to make ruby-electric.el work in emacs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs

I have installed ruby-electric.el to enable autopairing for def and end. I have required it in the .emacs file and evaluated the buffer.

However when I type 'def' in the buffer I dont see a corresponding 'end' block being added. How do I test what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable it in `ruby-mode` buffers. For example, this way:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ruby-electric-mode)
```

The `end` keyword should be added when you type Space after `def`.

BTW, if you're using the version from [this repository](https://github.com/qoobaa/ruby-electric), you don't need to do the above, it already adds the hook in an `autoload` form. This is also the version that's packaged in [Tromey's ELPA repository](http://tromey.com/elpa/index.html).